# How is that possible that putty is able to connect in SSH2 with no password or public key

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

Here the problem : 
I connect on the SSH2 server using putty with default setting (IP, port, ssh). 
I did not enter any key.
When connecting to the server, putty ask for username and not for password.
How is that possible that I am able to connect in SSH2 without one of these two options ?
Here is the putty logs :

2016-10-26 18:51:24 Looking up host "13X.XXX.XXX.XXX"
2016-10-26 18:51:24 Connecting to 13X.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22
2016-10-26 18:51:24 Server version: SSH-2.0-IPSSH-6.9.0
2016-10-26 18:51:24 Using SSH protocol version 2
2016-10-26 18:51:24 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
2016-10-26 18:51:24 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
2016-10-26 18:51:25 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
2016-10-26 18:51:25 Host key fingerprint is:
2016-10-26 18:51:25 ssh-rsa 1023 51:a6:c5:5b:23:50:51:de:9f:94:78:52:1d:FF:FF:FF
2016-10-26 18:51:25 Initialised AES-128 CBC client->server encryption
2016-10-26 18:51:25 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
2016-10-26 18:51:25 Initialised AES-128 CBC server->client encryption
2016-10-26 18:51:25 Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
2016-10-26 18:51:27 Access granted
2016-10-26 18:51:27 Opening session as main channel
2016-10-26 18:51:27 Opened main channel
2016-10-26 18:51:28 Allocated pty (ospeed 38400bps, ispeed 38400bps)
2016-10-26 18:51:28 Started a shell/command

Thanks

Comment: If the server does not require any authentication, then it's possible. Not sure what your question is. Anyway, you urgently need to upgrade. The PuTTY 0.63 is pretty old and suffers many vulnerabilities.

Comment: In SSH2 is it possible to have a connection without private key and without password ? I was thinking that you have to provide one of these two. What I do not understand is that putty does not prompt for a password.

Comment: Yes it is possible, if the server is configured accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your precision. It helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The server that I was trying to connect does not need any private key or password.
Putty handle this connection well, but the python library paramiko connect method does not allow such connection.

If you met such issue, ensure that you SSH client allows to connect without password or private key. (I had to change the _auth of paramiko in order to successfully connect)